# php - Check Whether A given Value is A Domain or URL

Tags: php, regex, url

How to check if a user given value is url or just domain?

Example:

```
    $a = array('http://domain.com/page/ex.html',
    'http://domain.com/',
    'domain.com'
    );

foreach ($a as $v) {

if ($v is url)
// do something
} elseif ($v is domain) {
// do another thing
}

}
```

What should I do to check whether `$v` value is url or domain?

Comment: Pass the string into [parse_url](http://www.php.net/parse_url) and check what parts it has.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `parse_url`:

http://us.php.net/parse_url

```
foreach ($a as $v) {
   $url = parse_url($v);
   if (isset($url['host']) && $url['host'] != '') {
       // valid host
   }
}
```

Comment: Yea.. the cleanest solution!

Answer (score 2):

Use `filter_var($, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)` to test for URL. To test for domain you can either do a superficial error-prone regexp like `preg_match('~^[a-z0-9][a-z0-9\.-]*\.[a-z]+$~i', $);` or write a proper function that checks against consecutive dots, proper gtld, verifies lengths and more.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex,

Example: [live](http://codepad.viper-7.com/ZTSe0b)

```
        $domainRegex = '/^[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9-]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$/';
        $urlRegex = '/((([A-Za-z]{3,9}:(?:\/\/)?)(?:[-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)?[A-Za-z0-9.-]+|(?:www.|[-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)[A-Za-z0-9.-]+)((?:\/[\+~%\/.\w-_]*)?\??(?:[-\+=&;%@.\w_]*)#?(?:[\w]*))?)/';
        $a = array('http://domain.com/page/ex.html',
            'http://domain.com/',
            'domain.com'
        );

        foreach ($a as $v) {

            if (preg_match($urlRegex, $v)) {
                echo $v.': url<br/>';
            } else if (preg_match($domainRegex, $v)) {
                echo  $v.': domain<br/>';
            }
        }
```

Output should be:

```
http://domain.com/page/ex.html: url
http://domain.com/: url
domain.com: domain
```

Comment: `test.x123_xx.com.abdd-ddd.de` - is a valid domain, your regexp does not work on it. I'd not use RegExp when there are native PHP functions doing this job more reliable..

Comment: Just make the http optional and it works,and i just gave an option.

Comment: Your welcome! Just sayin other ways are more reliable IMO. I just read underscore is *not* a valid character in a domain, tho some sites offer it... not sure about this anyways. peace

Answer (score 0):

Well, not sure what is your definition for domain and url. From the example, I guess if any string contains a `/` then its a URL.

```
if(preg_match("|/|i", $v)){
    print "url\n";
}
```

Without regex:

```
if(strpos($v, "/")){
    print "url\n";
}
```

Comment: @vlzvl its a URL as it contains `/` according to my answer.